# Spotify's Android SDK returns a Type.EMPTY Authentication Response only when the Spotify App is installed

Tags: java, android, authentication, spotify, spotify-app

Below is the code I am running:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultIntent);

    Log.e("Spotify Auth", "Running login activity pt 2. result code: " + resultCode + " Request Code: " + requestCode);

    if(requestCode == 200){
        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, resultIntent);

        //log and store for later use
        if(response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN) {
            Log.e("Access Token Received", response.getAccessToken());

            getSharedPreferences("appPrefs", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit().putString("spotify_token", response.getAccessToken()).apply();

        } else if(response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.ERROR)
            Log.e("Spotify Access Token", "Code: " + response.getCode() + " Token failure: " + response.getError());
        else
            Log.e("Spotify Access Token", response.getType().name() + " " + response.getError() + " Token: " + response.getAccessToken());

    } else {
        Log.e("Spotify Access Token", "Token failure: " + resultCode + "   " + requestCode);
    }
}

public void getSpotifyAuth() {
    //spotify token setup
    AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder =
            new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(
                    getString(R.string.spotify_keys).split(":")[0],
                    AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN,
                    "com.lattestudios.musicpal://auth");
    builder.setShowDialog(true);
    AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();
    AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, 200, request);
}
```

Everything works fine when the spotify app is not installed. It gives a popup asking for login, then the user clicks agree and the SDK returns a token. When the spotify application is installed, however, a very quick loading screen pops up instead of the login screen because it is trying to get the token from the app. When this goes away, the response given in the onActivityResult function is of type EMPTY. The request code is correct, the result code is -1, and the error message and access token is null.

If you would like to see the rest of my code you can find it [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/latte164/MusicPal). Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected output in your case?

Comment: @LucasWieloch I am expecting to receive an authentication token. Based on [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-authentication/), it seems like it should just fetch a token from the app and return it normally instead of showing the popup like it does without spotify installed, but instead of Type.TOKEN it returns Type.EMPTY.

Comment: We also face this empty response on api 19 with Spotify app installed on device. If I uninstalled Spotify app and get authorization via browser working fine. It happened on api 19 only. 19 above working fine. Please help to identify the issues.

Comment: @SakthivelAppavu check the answer I posted below, it was an issue with the strings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that it was caused by attempting to use SSL proxying with Charles Proxy across all `*.spotify.com` domains. After I changed that to `api.spotify.com` the login started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I messed up the strings according to this GitHub documentation https://github.com/spotify/android-auth

```
<resources>
    <string name="com_spotify_sdk_redirect_scheme">yourscheme</string>
    <string name="com_spotify_sdk_redirect_host">yourhost</string>
</resources>
```

Make sure to put the scheme and host properly
e.g if the redirect url is playlists/callback, then set com_spotify_sdk_redirect_scheme to playlists and com_spotify_sdk_redirect_host to callback
Or also you can create the redirect host using these two strings

```
private fun getRedirectUri(): Uri {
    return Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(getString(R.string.com_spotify_sdk_redirect_scheme))
        .authority(getString(R.string.com_spotify_sdk_redirect_host))
        .build()
}
```

Also make sure that the redirect URI on Spotify dashboard matches these two and the one in the Manifest.